# “that ”at the beginning of a narrative sentence

Tags: grammar

> That I don't know if I am good at making friends.

I'm not sure if this sentence is grammatically correct, but I've noticed this phenomenon several times where a “that” is added at the beginning of a sentence. Could you tell me what grammatical use it has, or what impact it has on the meaning of a sentence？

Comment: //That I don't know if I am good at making friends....// sounds incomplete.  It should be complete, for instance, like,  "That [I don't know if I am good at making friends] is not a new information to my siblings. Without 'that' at the start, it makes complete sense.

Comment: _That I don't know if I am good at making friends_ is not a complete sentence; it's just a clause. _That_ in front of a tensed clause (never mind "narrative", that's not a grammar term) converts the clause into a dependent noun clause. The _that_ is called a "complementizer", and the clause is called a "complement clause". It can be the object of a verb, as in _She thinks that I don't know_, or it can be the subject of a verb, as @RamPillai suggested

Answer (score 1):

*That* is a demonstrative. It tells you who or what is being talked about.

It may follow the noun to which it refers. “See the red car in the parking lot? That car {the red one} is mine.”

It may follow the concept to which it refers. “We should stand in the shade. That {action} will keep us cool”.

Occasionally it is used to precede, as in the manner of your example. “That *I answer here on ELU* {a concept} is well-known to readers. That *I used to keep bees* is {a concept} novel to them”. “That I used to keep bees” is a phrase but not a sentence.

Your example similarly creates a phrase and is incomplete as a sentence. *That I don’t know if I am good at making friends* refers demonstratively to a concept but says nothing about it. An example of completion might be:

*That I don’t know if I am good at making friends shows my lack of self-awareness.*